# How to replace characters in a string with other characters?

Tags: javascript

I want to replace certain characters in a string with other characters. I´ve did my research and found that the best way is to use regular expressions...
But, something doesn´t work ...
Here´s what i did so far...

```
var alphabet = {
   'á':'a',
   'é':'e',
   'í':'i'
};

var word = $("input[name=phrase]").val();
alert(word);  //output: ok!

var url = word.replace(/áéí|/g, function(s) {
    return alphabet[s];
});

alert(url); //output: undefined,undefined,undefined...
```

Comment: Is the pipe a typo or really part of your code?

Comment: Thought so, just making sure. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match any of those characters using `[]`, <s>and capture the match(es) using `()`</s> instead of looking for a match of those *consecutive* characters.

```
var url = word.replace(/[áéí]/g, function(s) {
    return alphabet[s];
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/5UmLV/1/

---

As noted by [@Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) the capture group was unnecessary. Updated to reflect that improvement.

Comment: Is a capture group really necessary? Anyways, +1.

Comment: No, not necessary. `word.replace(/[áéí]/g, function(s) {return alphabet[s];})` works fine.

Comment: thanks... that idea works. What if there is more then 1 character to be replace. like '...' : '' how does it go in the regular expressions? i tried using quotes, like '...' but then it confuses the actual quote with a replacement character  '\'' : ''

Comment: @Marco: Then get rid of the `[]` , and use `|` to separate the possibilities: `/á|é|í|\.\.\./g` http://jsfiddle.net/5UmLV/4/

Comment: @Marco: Are you sure these are three dots? Maybe you have an [ellipsis](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Elipsis), which is one character. Just saying that not everything that looks like multiple characters consists of multiple characters ;)